# Derivatives in Sobolev spaces involving time

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and consider for $T>0$ a function $u \in H^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$. Is it possible to speak about $u_t(T^-)$, i.e. the one-sided derivative in $T$ from the left? In general, is the expression
$$
\int_\Omega u_t(T^-) u(T) \, dx
$$
well defined?

Comment: No, it is not well defined. The derivative $u_t$ is not more regular than any function in $L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega))$ and you cannot perform point evaluations on those functions.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was confused about the fact that given $u \in H^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ then $u \in C([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$, but I realized that's not sufficient for having well-defined one-sided derivatives.